# Regular expression lookbhind in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm attempting to remove the entire anchor tag and its contents. This would leave me the text that follows.

**Initial String:**

```
<a>Text inside</a> Some text that follows
```

**Expected:**

```
Some text that follows
```

I've been getting conflicting answers on how lookbacks work and don't work in the current state of JavaScript.

I've looked [here](https://2ality.com/2019/10/regexp-lookaround-assertions.html) and other places, but when implimenting a lookback, I run into issues. Every regex generator I use says its not supported in JavaScript.

Comment: And why do you need a lookbehind?

Comment: Because they're not supported (universally) in JavaScript--doesn't seem necessary, though--just replace with an empty string.